# How to change the color of dropdown inside a p-calendar primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using Angular with PrimeNg. I want to change the color of the selected element of the dropdown that appear inside the primeng component p-calendar I try to use JavaScript selecting the element but the color is not applied. Also I add a selector #calendar to use viewchild in my component but I don't know if this way I can chande the default color.

Someone know if this is possible to do?

Thank you very much

```
<p-calendar #calendar [inline]="inlineCalendar" [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="yearRangeValues" 
      [showButtonBar]="true" (onSelect)="onSelectDate($event)" (onMonthChange)="onSelectMonth($event)">

</p-calendar>


<p-calendar>
<select class="ui-datepicker-month ng-tns-c11-8 ng-star-inserted">
            <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "January,February,March,April,M"
}-->
            <option class="ng-tns-c11-8 ng-star-inserted" value="0">January</option>
            <option class="ng-tns-c11-8 ng-star-inserted" value="1">February</option>
            <option class="ng-tns-c11-8 ng-star-inserted" value="2">March</option>
            <option class="ng-tns-c11-8 ng-star-inserted" value="3">April</option>
            ...
        </select>
</p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below css together primeng class to change the color of selected option.

```
select.ui-datepicker-month:focus>option:checked{
  background-color: green;
}
select.ui-datepicker-year:focus>option:checked{
  background-color: red;
}
```

It will change the color of selected option
[image: Like this]

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-2ajk57)